# How to setup Go in GoClipse

Tags: go, goclipse

I installed goclipse in my eclipse, and setup the preferences as follows :

[Preferences->Go->Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhvdF.jpg)

[ProjectExplorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbPiV.jpg)

Now when I create a new GoFile (HelloWorld.src), the file is saved in D:/GO/TestProject/src. But when I build the same file, the bin and pkg folders are empty and hence when I run the file the following error comes :

**resource does not have a corresponding go package**

Unable to run the code because of this error.

Comment: Put your `HelloWorld.go` into a folder under `src`, e.g. `src\hello\HelloWorld.go`. And you must start it with `package main` for it to be a runnable program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project path should be `D:\GO\src\TestProject` in order to match the workspace expected as described in https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Then, your GOPATH should point to `D:\GO` (NOT `...\src`)
The go tool will automatically use `$GOPATH/src`, `$GOPATH/bin` or `$GOPATH/pkg` when appropiate for each case.

And as icza pointed out, your program should have a `package main` statement on the top of your go file to be recognized as an executable, unless you want to create a package, in that case, you should name your package as you want.

Comment: But when I add a new project the default location for the project comes as D:/Go and Not D;/go/src/TestProject
But when I change the location to d:/Go/src/testProject the bin and pkg folders are not made and the Go file is not build.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think the default location for a project is based on the Workspace configuration from Eclipse. 

About your compilation problems, can you provide the output for the `go build` or `go install` commands so we can see what's the problem and why the pkg/bin folders aren't being created?

Comment: Did you check if bin and pkg folders where created in `D:/Go`? (Not `D:/Go/src/testProject`)